# session_id empty on some pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables, sessionid

As silly as it sounds, I'm baffled by this behavior:

In my PHP code I am calling `session_start();` before anything else (not even a space before it is called). I can test this by setting a session variable and then echoing said variable.

If I run the following code on one of my pages I get an expected session ID back, but if I run it on one of post pages used for ajax then it comes up empty. Only sessions that I set on the ajax post page specifically can be seen, not session variables set from another page.

```
 $a = session_id();
 var_dump($a);
```

I know I'm going to get responses telling me to make sure my `session_start();` has been called from the beginning, but I swear up and down it is (if it wasn't, sessions wouldn't work locally on that page).

What in the world could be causing this strange behavior?

FWIW, adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` doesn't give me any info other than telling me I have an undefined variable when trying to dump a session var that was set from another page.

Comment: how long your session lasts? make sure the page doesn't destroy session finally make sure you're calling the correct session variable.

Answer (score 0):

How do you navigate between the pages? If you're using `header`, the session data isn't always written before leaving the first page. I had to use

```
session_write_close(); 
header('Location: page2.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that session_start() is implemented correctly and $a shows on some pages but not on specific pages, I would say it is most likely because session variables are super global and maybe on those pages you have a global variable $a.

Comment: The $a was just for testing purposes, I could just as easily have called it $abcdefg. $a is not a global variable in my code, anywhere.

Comment: In my turn, I gave $a as an example too. The bottom line is to find if there is a global variable with the same name. This problem happened to me and I fixed it by changing the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being caused by my /tmp partition being full. I have a headless dropbox installation on this server and it decided to update itself overnight last night to a new version and not clean up behind itself. I should have gotten a notification that the /tmp partition was full but I did not for some reason so I didn't even think about it being the cause.

Let this be a warning to others who find they have the same problem I did. I'm still not entirely sure why I was able to set a new session variable on the problem page or even set the session vars for the other pages to begin with if the /tmp was full.

I appreciate everyone's willingness to help out though!